# SSL Error for Sentry v2.10 with Laravel 6.20.27 (PHP v7.4.19)

Tags: php, laravel, ssl-certificate, sentry

I am using sentry (version 2.10) with Laravel v6.20.27 and PHP v7.4.19. I follow the same steps mentioned in the documentation (https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/php/guides/laravel/other-versions/laravel5-6/). However I am not able to proceed as I am getting the below error

```
There was an error sending the event.
SDK: Failed to send the event to Sentry. Reason: "SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK for "https://oXXXXXXX.ingest.sentry.io/api/XXXXXXXX/store/".".
Please check the error message from the SDK above for further hints about what went wrong.
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I faced the same issue on my local. I'm using Laragon on Windows.

I downloaded a new cacert.pem file using this [link](https://curl.se/docs/caextract.html)

Just replace it with the one you currently have in your ssl folder. Hope this will fix your issue.

Comment: replace to this file

X:\laragon\etc\ssl\cacert.pem

Answer (score 0):

When you generate SSL certificate, you have to specify the host or server name. If it doesn't match to your  real host or server name you see this error.
Check this repo https://gitlab.com/damp-stack/mysql-ssl-docker/-/blob/master/gencerts.sh fake-server should be equal to your server name.